# Replacing marks in dataframe rows

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this kind of Python pandas dataframe, top row are columns:

```
Gender,Age,Weight,Height
    Male, 55, (82), 180
    Female, 34,(55),167
    Female,44,(67),182
    Male,81,(73),175
    Male,44,34,(87),185
```

How I can get rid of the "()" marks in weight column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vectorised `str.replace` to remove the parentheses:

```
In [189]:
df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].str.replace('[\(\)]','')
df

Out[189]:
   Gender  Age Weight  Height
0    Male   55     82     180
1  Female   34     55     167
2  Female   44     67     182
3    Male   81     73     175
4    Male   44     87     185
```